# Accessing Lines Chord Diagram D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization, chord-diagram

I'm working on fading out certain lines from a chord diagram when a separate chart is hovered over.  I'm looking at the code for the "fade" function,

```
`function fade(opacity) {
  return function(g, i) {
    svg.selectAll(".chord path")
    .filter(function(d) { return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i; })
    .transition()
    .style("opacity", opacity);
  };
 }`
```

And I was just wondering if someone could explain to me what d.source.index means and d.target.index mean. I generally understand that it's the source of the chord and the target of the chord, but I wanted to gain some more specific insight into the values/meaning of "index" so that I could better manipulate the selection.

My ultimate goal is to over over a box in a separate legend rectangle, and have the chord diagram  fade so that only the color hovered over in the legend box retains full opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Every chord has data associated with it. This data has, among other things, `source` and `target` attributes, which point to the nodes that the chord connects. In the code above, the `index` attribute of the source and target nodes is referenced to identify which ones to filter. This can be anything you want though.

In your application, depending on what the legend is for, you would need to check the value displayed in the legend for the source/target nodes or the chord itself.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still stuck now on determining how to best manipulate the data in the chord objects.  The only information I have is the color of the legend item being hovered over.  How can I apply the filter so that chords whose source aren't that color get dimmed?  Or, how can i edit the chord group data to include some other kind of identifier more accessible to me? I can clarify if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well presumably some attribute of the data is being mapped to the colors shown in the legend. This is what you would be looking for.